# Uncaught TypeError: this.is is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting error on `this.is`. is there any alternatives?

```
 function UpdateTotalPrice() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        if (id.indexOf("chkSelected") > -1) {
            if (this.checked && this.is(':disabled')==false) {
              //  alert(id);
                getPrice(this);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Try `$(this).is(':disabled')`. `.is()` is jQuery, not native JS

Comment: You need to re-wrap it in order to use jQuery functions: `$(this).is(...)` (`this` is the HTMLElement). The first order of debugging: `console.log(this)` to make sure it is what you think it is.

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/): _"More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword **`this` refers to the element**."_

Comment: The comments above are correct, but just FWIW the simplest, most direct way is `&& !this.disabled`. Although you can do `&& $(this).is(":disabled") == false`, it's extremely round-about in at least two different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this as a jQuery object. for example `$(this)`.
Your code should look like this:

```
 function UpdateTotalPrice() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).id;
        if (id.indexOf("chkSelected") > -1) {
            if ($(this).checked && $(this).is(':disabled')==false) {
              //  alert(id);
                getPrice(this);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This was already marked as dupe; thanks to your answer OP can no longer delete the question.

Comment: @ChrisG As long as no one upvotes it, they can still delete, but yeah, answering duplicates is not cool.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ah, good to know!